# IOS8 Push Notifications

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ios7, push-notification, ios8

I'm trying to register Ipad for push notifications without any luck. I have tried the following code but getting the error on IOS8 "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later." although its working fine on IOS7.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];


    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        NSLog(@"+++++++++++++");

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"============");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Better Way :**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    // use registerUserNotificationSettings
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    // use registerForRemoteNotifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
}
```

Comment: I have tried the mentioned code now getting this error

2014-10-11 13:00:53.555 test app[927:173651] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.